# Image inside imageview is not visible at runtime

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an imageview in the center of the screen defined in a xib file

several runs ago -> the image displayed and everything was ok

Now, for some reason, the image is visible in the interface builder, but is not there at runtime

I've tried with and without constraints

I triple checked that the image it displays is there in the project bundle

The image property hidden is set to NO

what could cause the image NOT to display at run time ?

with a curious thing: in the next screen the image IS there

Comment: Check the frame of the image view at runtime. Also, check to see that your layout did not somehow get messed up and that another view is hiding your image view.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a localization issue. It seems that if i load the xib file from a specific bundle, and not the main bundle. It wont be able to find the images of it, if the images are not localized as well